# Azure Website publish "The type 'System.Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced”

Tags: .net, azure

I upgraded my web application to `.Net Framework 4.6.1` and made quite a few other changes. When I published to `azurewebsite` I got the error:

> Compiler Error CS0012: The type 'System.Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly "System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"

So, I added to the `web.config` the lines

```
<compilation>
  <assemblies>
     <add assembly="System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
```

Now when I publish I just get a `500 error` so I am not sure if it got further or not as far as there is no information.

Answer (score 1):

The '500 error' was caused by having added a duplicate 'compilation' section to the web.config. I discovered this by publishing the web site to another local workstation. Once I fixed the duplicate, everything worked correctly.